# javascript не хочет выполнять функцию

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css-animation

хочу сделать так чтобы при нажатии на параграф вызывалась функция в которой прописано действие. но почему то она не хочет работать. подскажите что я сделал не так? Причем, когда вставил код  на оверфлов то тут он работает, а в гугл хроме нет.

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
console.log(p);
p[0].onclick = one;

function one(){
 alert('work');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="main.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body id="body">
  <p>Текст</p>
  <p>Текст</p>
  <p>Текст</p>
  <p>Текст</p>
  <p>Текст</p>
 </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Обратите внимание на знаки "галочка" слева от ответов на Ваши вопросы. Создатели сайта поместили их туда специально для Вас.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что "в гугл хроме" скрипт расположен в странице выше `<body>` и выполняется, когда элементов `<p>` еще нет.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  console.log(p);
  p[0].onclick = one;

  function one(){
    alert('work');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Либо, как вариант, скрипт можете подключить с атрибутом `defer`: `<script src="main.js" defer></script>`. При этом скрипт будет загружен асинхронно, но исполнится только после того, как весь документ будет обработан браузером.